# Open two links after javascript executes. One in a new tab one in current

Tags: javascript, html, function, hyperlink, onclick

I am managing a rather large site (few hundred pages) and I am looking for a way to execute javascript - then open one link in current tab and another in a new tab. The Href link works fine after the countdown it executes. But the js link is ignored. How to get both to open after the countdown finishes?

html

```
    <a href="http://www.example.com/here"      onclick="startTimer(this);return false; window.open('http://www.example.com/newtab');">anchor text</a>
```

js

```
<script>
function startTimer2(theLink2) {
    userInput = 25;
    if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

        function display1( notifier, str ) {
            document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML ='Please Wait: ' + str;


        }

        function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
            return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
        }

        function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
            (function countdown() {
                display1("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));        
                actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
                (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            })();

        }

        setTimer(userInput, {
            0: function () {  window.location=theLink2.href;  }
        }); 

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `startTimer2()` so it takes two arguments: the link and the URL to open in a new window. Then call `window.open()` when the timer runs out.

```
function startTimer2(theLink2, windowURL) {
    userInput = 25;
    if(userInput.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value");
    } else {
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

        function display1( notifier, str ) {
            document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML ='Please Wait: ' + str;


        }

        function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
            return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
        }

        function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
            (function countdown() {
                display1("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));        
                actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
                (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            })();

        }

        setTimer(userInput, {
            0: function () {
                window.open(windowURL);
                window.location=theLink2.href;
            }
        }); 

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="http://www.example.com/here" onclick="startTimer2(this, 'http://www.example.com/newtab');return false;">anchor text</a>
```

Comment: This opens the window immediately . I would like it to wait until the timer function is finished. It still delays the second link though... so progress.

Comment: I've been at this for hours admittedly my js is not good but a solution to this is evading me

Comment: Then you should call `window.open()` in the function that runs when the timer is finished, not in the `onclick`.

Comment: Yes this will work but i did not want to create a js function for all the website pages. But use one function. Or no js at all if it were possible

Comment: Is there a way to pass the window.open value to the js function?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can pass the URL to the function.

Comment: Awesome this seems to be working. But i got a popup blocked error after the timer stopped and only one link loaded

Comment: Also i would like to open the windowURL link in a new tab.

Comment: You need to turn off your popup blocker. When a window is opened outside the function that's called from clicking on something, the browser treats it as a popup.

Comment: Javascript can't control whether `window.open` uses a tab or window. There's no function for opening tabs.